# CardView items not clickable?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have items in my `CardView`, but the `onClickListener` will not work on these items?

Any Idea?
In my Code the `CardView` get visible and clickable when opening it.
But when i m clicking on the items it wont work.
I have tested everything, rebuild/clean the project etc.
The Cardview is opening when clicking on an other imageView, than it gets visible and clickable.

```
 <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/searchBarFickFrameLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/searchGHUCardView"
        style="@style/CardView"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/firstLinearLayoutSelection"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/searchSheetSetUser"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_user"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />


                <ImageView
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/searchSheetSetGroup"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_group"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />


                <TextView
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/searchSheetSetHashtag"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="#"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />

            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstLinearLayoutSelection"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="@string/txt_suche_user"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="@string/txt_suche_gruppe"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:text="@string/txt_suche_hashtag"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove below 2 line from your `CardView` in xml code;

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: not working, i said that it gets activated in the code. Now i removed it and tested, but still not working.